# When does an Elastic Beanstalk Instance IP address change?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to be able to change the IP address on my Elastic Beanstalk instance regularly.  It doesn't seem to change every time I restart it or change the code, how can I force it to update the IP address?

Answer (score 0):

The IP Address changes when you do an Environment Rebuild. During a rebuild, the underlying resources are all destroyed and created again resulting in your instances having different IP addresses.

I have posted a [comprehensive guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58066012/4523373) on how this can be achieved in another question.